# Удаление дублирующих записей в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, table, delete

Как удалить из таблице А в колонке В, значение которые повторяются в таблице А1 в колонке В1?

DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.telnum IN (SELECT telnum FROM black_list);

Используя такую командную строку дублирующие записи удаляются из обеих таблиц, а надо чтоб удалялось только из таблицы customers, а в таблице black_list оставались бы.

Answer (score 1):

Сама по себе команда `DELETE` удаляет только из таблицы указаной в `FROM`.

Если при этом автоматически удаляются записи из `black_list` это означает, что либо существует внешний ключ с поля `telnum` в таблице `black_list` на поле `telnum` в таблице `customers` с опцией каскадного удаления, либо есть `ON DELETE` триггер на таблице `customers`, в котором исполняется `DELETE` из `black_list`.

В зависимости от того, какой из этих вариантов у вас, будет отличаться и способ решения. В первом случае нужно убрать внешний ключ. Во втором - изменить триггер.

И еще одно замечание по терминологии. Дублирующими записями обычно называют записи в той же таблице, которые в некотором смысле "равны" существующим. Например, если бы в таблице `customers` было бы две записи с одинаковым значением в поле `telnum`, тогда можно было бы сказать, что имеем дублирующие записи по полю `telnum`.

Записи в одной таблице представляют собой однородные сущности, которые трактуются одинаково, поэтому имеет смысл говорить о дублировании. А в вашем случае скорее не дублирующие записи, а "соответствующие", т.к. смысл записей в таблицах `customers` и `black_list` скорее всего разный.

Comment: Спасибо. Я наоборот добавил Prmary Key и все заработало.